# Background image gets too big when adding background-attachment: fixed

Tags: css, background, fixed

On my site, I want the body to scroll over my header image. With `background-attachment: fixed`, it works, but the image gets way too big after which my title is not readable anymore. In other words, the `background-size: cover`, doesn't work anymore when I add `background-attachment: fixed`.

Curious if anyone else has had this problem and if anyone has a solution for this.

Here is my code:

```
.site-header {
   background: url("https://howtogetrippedathome.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/How-To-Get-Ripped-At-Home-Header-Image.png") top;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

PS2, my site: https://howtogetrippedathome.com/

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question's problem statement itself, consider improving this question by providing a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: have you tried `background-size: 100%` ? but for me, it works fine (takes cover) in FF 57

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`background-attachment: fixed` will handle the image as if the element was 100% height and width of the viewport. Therefore `background-size: cover;` will resize the image height to fit the viewport.

Try using `background-size: 100% auto;` (`100%` of the width | `auto` will set the height in a way that won't stretch the image)

I tested it on your side and with that edit it works 100%.

Unfortunately I can not add a code snipped because it will size the background to stackoverflows viewport and not to the code-sippets viewport.